# Need to insert simple html to div using js template

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates

now its looks

```
$("#grid").append("<div class='headline'><input type='text' placeholder='header' class='head'></div>");
```

**need easy way to move html to other file for clear and understandable
code**

Comment: try using one of the following sites to create an example for us to look at : jsfiddle.net, jsbin.com.  Its not clear from your question what you are wanting to do

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean for:

> move html to other file

?

You can set the html with JavaScript using:

```
$("#grid").html("<div class='headline'><input type='text' placeholder='header' class='head'></div>");
```

Comment: it works, but i want make it clear. I have much divs to add, when it calls. Need to shore it like "template"

Comment: You mean something like:

function(div_id, content){
  $("#"+div_id).html(content);
}

When you need to set the content for a specific div you can call the function to set the div's content.

Comment: i mean somethinklike

`$("#addheader").click(function(){

$("box").add(header);

}`

when header set in another template.js or .html i dont know as 

`"<input type='text' class='head'>" `

Comment: You can use the `$.getScript()` from JQuery, like:

`$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
console.log( data ); // Data returned
console.log( textStatus ); // Success
console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
console.log( "Load was performed." );
});`

See: [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)